# Tracing to see where Ansible hangs

Tags: ansible

My Ansible tasks hangs. I use `-vvvv`, but nevertheless I can't see any useful information.

```
<coffee-and-sugar.club> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<coffee-and-sugar.club> SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="root"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/guettli/.ansible/cp/544631aae4 -tt coffee-and-sugar.club '/bin/sh -c '"'"'/usr/bin/python3 /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1608394831.3465264-205483640933119/AnsiballZ_pip.py && sleep 0'"'"''
```

What can I do to see what is going on?

Is there a way to enable tracing (like `set -x` in a shell script)?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the python script on the remote server by hand. In my case this revealed the root-cause.

Example:

```
ssh root@remote

# /usr/bin/python3 /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1608394831.3465264-205483640933119/AnsiballZ_pip.py

The authenticity of host 'github.com (140.82.121.3)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?
```